# Xubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 Python dependency issues

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, 15.10, python, dependencies

I have upgraded from XUbuntu 15.10 to 16.04 earlier today.  After going through the upgrade, and running into a few issues throughout the upgrade.  It has completed, but now I'm having issues with unmet python dependencies.  I can't quite seem to figure out what I need to do to fix it.

```
root@Norns:/home/kevinl# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
python
Suggested packages:
  python-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 46.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.11-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status1
Errors were encountered while processing:
   python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run dpkg --configure -a I get the following:

```
root@Norns:/home/kevinl# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-dev:
 python-dev depends on python (= 2.7.11-1); however:
  Version of python on system is 2.7.9-1.

dpkg: error processing package python-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.11-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for python-support:
 python-support depends on python-minimal; however:
  Package python-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-dev
 python-minimal
 python-support
```

I've tried removing the version it states is on system, but it won't remove.  Gives me a long list of all the various dependencies that are not met and simply states "won't be installed".  If anyone can help, would be appreciated.  Thank you.